# Convert MySql Database to SQLite (Tricky!)

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Firstly i know that there have been many questions asked about this! But i have a problem furthermore.

- What i'm doing is, im exporting my database (MySql) to a .sql file, through phpmyadmin. No problem. When i then try to import it to either "SQLite Database Browser" or "phpliteadmin" it gives error.

The errors is because of a wrong format from phpmyadmin.
 SqLite wants this format:

```
INSERT INTO "tablename" ("field1", "field2", "field3", "field 4") VALUES ('0', 'hi', '0', '0');
```

But this is what phpmyadmin gives (Notice the missing apostrophes when its clear numbers.)

```
INSERT INTO "tablename" ("field1", "field2", "field3", "field 4") VALUES (0, 'hi', 0, 0);
```

Is there any solution? (I guess there is, but i can't see it..)

Comment: SQLite does not want quotes around numbers. Show the error message.

Comment: I solved this, because i misunderstood the error. The error was because of some quotes inside quotes, which i just fixed by replacing all quotes in the database by double quotes, and woila. :) (" '' " will be made to " ' " in the final product anyway) Sorry for wasting your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, because i misunderstood the error. The error was because of some quotes inside quotes, which i just fixed by replacing all quotes in the database by double quotes, and woila. :) (" '' " will be made to " ' " in the final product anyway) Sorry for wasting your time! :)